# Xtreme Download Manager notification icon

Tags: 14.04, system-tray, downloaders

Instead of the notification icon being in the tray, it now floats on the screen. This is really annoying because it blocks other items on the screen.
I've already tried completely removing and re-installing, but it does nothing.
what should I do?
I'm on ubuntu 14.04
Cinnamon desktop

Comment: Have you tried pulling it over into the system tray?